# ReactJS app on SSL

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS and am trying to test deploying to a web server.

It's just one component that says hello, to make sure everything is working.

It works fine on local host, but when I upload to my webserver, which is configured for SSL, it does not work.

Works: http://careigniter.com/x/test/

Does Not work: https://careigniter.com/x/test/

Is there something special you have to do if you are going to serve the entire app under SSL?

Comment: in my  system it is working.both the links are working.Both the links are showing `Hello! asdf`

Comment: Both links actually work :D

Comment: Yeah, both links works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

The issue is that server has wordpress and some caching, that is probably what is going on.  I should have just started on a fresh server to begin with.